# How to minify html with laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I use laravel 5.6 in my project.

For example: I need minify `index.php` with laravel mix.

I used to work with Laravel-Elixir.

How to minify HTML with laravel mix ?

Comment: What do you mean by "minify html"?

Comment: @NicoHaase , Hi, Yes in need compress HTML with Laravel mix. I used to work with Laravel-Elixir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mercuryseries/laravel-elixir-minify-html

This package allows you to minify your static HTML files or the HTML that gets generated by your Blade template files.

Enjoy !